# PowerApps Gallery items shrinking on save

Tags: powerapps

Whenever I save my PowerApps app, the items in vertical Galleries 'shrink' to a horizontal size smaller than the components in them.  See attached images.  I've tried changing various properties, but can't seem to fix this problem. I manually resize the gallery item after each save, but I'm at a loss for anything to try to fix this issue.

I have noticed that on save the TemplateWidth of the gallery resets to a value smaller than the gallery width. There doesn't seem to a way to set TemplateWidth directly.  Frustrating.

Also I tried recreating this in a brand new App and wasn't getting this issue.  It's almost like something is corrupt 'under the hood'.  Not sure how to even debug such a thing.  Do I need to recreate my entire application from scratch?

[image]
[image]

[image: PropertiesTab]
[image]

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of the properties pane?

Comment: What code is run `OnSelect` of the "Save" button?